# How to avoid this error (502 Bad Gateway, PhpStorm)

Tags: php, phpstorm

this code work correctly:

```
ver. 1 for ($i=0; $i<4; $i*=2){echo $i."<br>";
```

but if I change it to this:

```
ver.2 for ($i=0; $i<4; $i^2=2){echo $i."<br>";
```

I received communicate:

**Error**

> "502 Bad Gateway"

BTW: in `ver. 1` I can change values and add some simple commands and it still work correctly
Why?

Comment: What URL do you use when running this code? If it's PhpStorm's built-in simple  web server, then yes -- it can give 502 code for unknown reason for a perfectly valid code. Solution -- use proper web server (Apache/nginx/IIS etc) and define Deployment entry (URL from there is used when you use "Open in browser" kind of functionality)

Comment: Good. You may watch after https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31859 ticket if you are interested in using PhpStorm's built-in web server

Comment: The second code is wrong. Why do you expect it works ?